# ATMEGA168A - Using timer

Tags: c, timer, embedded, atmega

I am trying to understand how to use timers with my ATMEGA168A, however the example I have [(link)](https://sites.google.com/site/qeewiki/books/avr-guide/counter-atmega328) doesn't seem to work since it returns 0 all the time.

My idea is to make a HC-SR04 [(link)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y-yZnNhMYy7rwhAgyL_pfa39RsB-x2qR4vP8saG73rE/edit#) ultra sound sensor work.

```
#define F_CPU   1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

long measure(){
    //Setting up the timer
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);

    //Setting trigger as output
    DDRD |= (1 << PD1);

    //Setting echo as input
    PORTD |= (1 << PD2);

    //Triggering the hardware
    PORTD ^= (1 << PD1);
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTD ^= (1 << PD1);

    //Waiting until echo goes low
    TCNT1 = 0;
    while(bit_is_clear(PIND, PD2));
    long timer_value = TCNT1;

    //Calculating and returning the distance
    long distance = timer_value / 58.82;
    return distance;
}
```

How can I successfully measure the amount of time the PD2 was high?

Comment: In what way does it seem to not work? Crash? Wrong timing? Doesn't start? Catches fire?

Comment: Are you sure a clock signal is provided for the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure the amount of time the PD2 was high, write some code to do so, compile, write it to your microcontroller and turn on it.

Not tested, try this:

```
#define F_CPU   1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

long measure(){
    //Setting up the timer
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | (1 << CS10);

    //Setting trigger as output
    DDRD |= (1 << PD1);

    //Setting echo as input
    PORTD |= (1 << PD2);

    //Triggering the hardware
    PORTD ^= (1 << PD1);
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTD ^= (1 << PD1);

    //Waiting until echo goes low (after Initiate)
    while(!bit_is_clear(PIND, PD2));
    //Waiting until echo goes high (Echo back starts)
    while(bit_is_clear(PIND, PD2));
    TCNT1 = 0;
    //Waiting until echo goes low (Echo back ends)
    while(!bit_is_clear(PIND, PD2));
    long timer_value = TCNT1;

    //Calculating and returning the distance
    long distance = timer_value / 58.82;
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Unfortunately the "while(!bit_is_clear(PIND, PD2));" is an endless loop

Comment: I wrote two `while(!bit_is_clear(PIND, PD2));`. Which do you mean?

Comment: What if you connect the input to a switch and send some signal manually instead of connecting to the sensor?